# Different versions of android, different display

Tags: android, html, css, cordova, ionic-framework

I have created a mobile application using ionic framework. It consist of many html pages. For android version **KitKat**, the pages are displaying correctly. For android version **Jellybean**, the pages are displaying differently. Please see the html &css code?

**Login.html**

```
<ion-view hide-nav-bar="true ">
    <ion-content scroll="false">
        <div class="row" style="padding:29px">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="text-center">
                    <h1 class="text-font-white">Welcome</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="line-white"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <input class="input" placeholder="{{user}}">
                </input>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <input class="input" type="password" placeholder="{{password}}">
                </input>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" style="padding:30px 0">
            <div class="col">
                <button type=submit id="login-btn" ng-click="doLogin()"></button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" style="padding:2px 0">
            <div class="col">
                <button type=submit class="btn-white" ng-click="openRegistration()">Register your account</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" style="padding:34px 0">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="item item-image" id="logo">
                    <img src="img/logo.png">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="text-center">
                    <h4>Forgot password?
                <span><a href="#/forgetpwd" style="text-decoration:none;color:white">
                      Recover it</a></span>
                    </h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

**style.css** [I have included styles that is related to Log.html page]

```
ion-view {
    background-image: url("../img/bg.png") !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover
}
.text-font-white {
    color: white;
}
.text-font-white {
    color: white;
}
.line-white {
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url("../img/title_line_white.png");
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 20px
}
.input {
    width: 97%;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 2px solid rgba(256, 256, 256, .4);
    padding: 4px;
    font-family: 'Lato-Black';
}
#login-btn {
    width: 97%;
    background: transparent;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 2px solid rgba(256, 256, 256, .4);
    padding: 14px;
    background-image: url("../img/icon_key.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 28px;
}

#logo {
    background-color: transparent;
    border-width: 0
}
```

Different versions of android shows design differently, how to solve the problem?

Comment: try using a support lib. plugin (something like [this](https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/cordova-plugin-android-support-v4))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different Android versions have different WebView, with different support for html/css. For example [svg](http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg) is only partially supported before android 4.4.

Unfortunately only from Android 4.4 it's possible to [remote debug](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging) your application with Chrome.

Check manually what css properties are failing across different Android version, then try to find a workaround (search and ask here).

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Visit below link, you can get more ideas about Android Screen Sizes from it:

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: This is not an answer to this question in any possible way.

Comment: @Gajotres:Do you have anu idea about this?